# Image not optimizing for product page

Tags: product, import, product-images, product-page, magento2.3.0

I import products from CSV file. I added base_image, small_image, thumnail_image, swatch_image and additional_image column. In backend it had been updated. But in front-end shows default magento icon.

Front end image link goes to cache folder eg.,( http://35.246.29.162/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/74c1057f7991b4edb2bc7bdaa94de933/T/rugs/flatweave/cottage/cottage-ct5191/cottage-blue/cottage-blue-zigzag-pattern-floor-rugs-blue-fullview-e-rugs.jpg )

Please let me know to fix this solution.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to System > CacheManagement

Click "Flush catalog images cache" at the bottom.

And click "Flush magento cache", "Flush cache storage" on the top.

And then you will see your image being resized & regenerated on frontend.

Comment: I lost all my images.